# Why there is error in assigning values to QString

Tags: c++, qt, setter, qstring

I want to access the Qstring (m_IPAdd)  from a `Dialog Window` to `Main Window`. However, I am stuck in passing a Qstring value in a setter function.

My error appears as a pop-up window when debug mode:

```
unhandled exception occurs at 0x66a77448 (Qt5Cored.dll) in __.exe:0xC0000005: 
conflict happend when accessing the memory at 0xffffffffffffffff"
```

(I am using MSVC2010 with Qt5.0. )

**Dialog Window:**

```
private:
MainWindow *mainwindow;
```

...

```
mainwindow->setIPAdd(m_IPAdd);     //m_IPAdd: member variable of class DialogWindow
```

**MainWindow:**

```
private:    
QString m_ip;
```

...

```
void MainWindow::setIPAdd(const QString ip)
{
    m_ip = ip ;
}
```

I also tried

```
void MainWindow::setIPAdd(const QString ip)
{
    QString ipadd = ip;        //ipadd: local variable which it can get the value of Qstring (in Debug mode) 
    m_ip = ipadd ;             //here's the program crashes, m_ip can't get any value
}
```

I am wondering why the local variable `ipadd` can get the value passed through argument `ip`, but not `m_ip`. I have even tried assigning

```
m_ip = "abc";
```

but the program also fails.

I have read through docs in qt web, but still don't know which part is useful to me.

Please give me any guides and advice. Thank you very much!!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: 1. Was the object containing m_ip properly instantiated?

Comment: What does your debugger say? I'm guessing the `MainWindow` instance doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Bet that pointer to `MainWindow` (aka `mainwindow`) is not initialized

Comment: @MarkoFrelih, @cmannett85 : thanks, updated the error.  @borisbn : do you mean initializing that pointer to `MainWindow` in constructor of `Dialog Window`? @AlexanderVX: does it mean I need to new a QString object?

Comment: @borisbn: thanks!! I didn't initialize the mainwindow pointer. And now it works fine! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dialog Window inherits from QWidget, it is a widget itself. So... you can just define your own Q_PROPERTY on it to represent the value you want to share, and register that property. With that it will be accesible from your mainwindow.

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't give enough information. I'm suspecting that your pointer is invalid or main window gets destroyed before it receives the result.
2. you did wrong. You have Qt so use signal and slots to pass values between dialog and main window. Properly written dialog should be a closed box which is unaware of surroundings or who created it, but you given it a pointer to main window.